# Scripting: reading file from remote machine and store in dir variable

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scripting, remote-access

I have two machines.. Im running a bash shell from remote machine where i do a ssh to the machines (ssh keys already shared) and then try reading from a file.
However, when I do a ssh it goes into prompt.. wait for some command and then executes the next line of the script.

```
 Proc_m1_s1$ cat CleanCounters.txt  
 /root/karan/Logs/Counters/        
 /root/karan/Logs/Signalling/
```

Script

```
while [ $i -le 12 ]  
   do  
    IP_Addr="IP$i"  
    ssh $UNAME@${!IP_Addr}  
    for dir in $(cat /root/karan/bin/CleanCounters.txt); do  
       find $dir -name "A*" -type f -mtime +60 |xargs rm -f  
    done  
    i=$(( i+1 ))  
 done
```

I get the result in the following way...

```
[csbackup@muarchive BackupFolderNames]$ /home/csbackup/BackupFolderNames/CleanLogs_MUTUNDWE.sh  
Last login: Tue Jun 23 11:13:14 2015 from o2net2  
Proc_m1_s1$  
Proc_m1_s1$ exit  
logout  
Connection to 10.0.0.1 closed.  
cat: /root/karan/bin/CleanCounters.txt: No such file or     directory*
```

Can anyone help me out so that i can remotely cat the lines of the file in dir variable and use it my script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute remote commands via `ssh` as follows (example cats `/etc/hosts` and stores it in a local variable):

```
result=`ssh $UNAME@${!IP_Addr} "cat /etc/hosts"`
```

This would answer the question stated in the title. For your `for` loop application, you would either have to write the entire command in one line or send a multi-line string as `ssh` parameter. Of course, you do things multiple times, which lead to multiple outputs. This output would then be stored in a single variable. In order to split this later on and assign this to the different loop values, add a "separator string" to the output, which you can then use to split the string later on.

Answer (score -1):

Below command will store remote file output in local server variable (dir):

```
ssh -t user@servername "dir=\$(cat /path/to/files ); echo "$out""
```